# c# object doesn't updates

Tags: c#, object, serialization, reference, deserialization

I'm trying to run primitive game server. So far I get to this point (commented line) and server runs smootly. But if I send object again from client, it doens't update more than once. 
So for example, client sends serialized player object with new position Vector2(400,50), but server deserliaze it to object that got old position.

Player code

```
namespace Commons.Game
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Unit
    {
        #region Fields
        public int ID;
        public Vector2 position;
        public string name;
        public int HP;
        public int XP;
        public int Lvl;
        public bool active;
        public float speed;
        public string password;
        #endregion

        public Unit(Vector2 position, int HP, float speed, string name, string password, int ID)
        {
            active = true;
            this.position = position;
            this.HP = HP;
            this.XP = 0;
            this.speed = speed;
            this.name = name;
            this.Lvl = 1;
            this.password = password;
            this.ID = ID;
        }
```

Server code

```
namespace SocketServer.Connection
{
    class Server
    {
        #region Fields
        Unit[] players;

        UdpClient playersData;

        Thread INHandlePlayers;

        BinaryFormatter bf;

        IPEndPoint playersEP;

        #endregion

        public Server()
        {
            this.players = new Unit[5];

            bf = new BinaryFormatter();

            this.playersData = new UdpClient(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 3001));
            this.playersEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 3001);

            this.INHandlePlayers = new Thread(new ThreadStart(HandleIncomePlayers));
            this.INHandlePlayers.Name = "Handle income players.";

            this.INHandlePlayers.Start();
        }

        private void HandleIncomePlayers()
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Players income handler started.");
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

            while (true)
            {
                byte[] data = playersData.Receive(ref playersEP);
                ms.Write(data, 0, data.Length); 
                ms.Position = 0;
                Unit player = null; 
                player = bf.Deserialize(ms) as Unit; //<-- 1st deserialization is OK, bu  after another client update, object doesn't change. So I change Vector with position at client, that sends correct position I want, but at server side position doesn't change after first deserialization.
                Console.Out.WriteLine(player.name + " " + player.position.X + " " + player.position.Y);
                ms.Flush();
                for (int i = 0; i < players.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (players[i] != null && player.ID == players[i].ID)
                    {
                        players[i] = player;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Does `Console.Out.WriteLine(player.name + " " + player.position.X + " " + player.position.Y);` show the old details or the new details?

Comment: Also, what makes you think you got a full message from `Receive`? As network code goes, that is **massively** unreliable. I suggest you need to look at "framing". I also think you are leaving garbage in the `MemoryStream` - setting the Length to 0 would be a good idea (after each iteration)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dude, I'm not quite sure about it, but I'd instantiate the MemoryStream object inside your loop, like below.

I can't try this code right know, sorry about that.

```
    private void HandleIncomePlayers()
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Players income handler started.");
        MemoryStream ms;

        while (true)
        {
            ms = new MemoryStream(); //here
            byte[] data = playersData.Receive(ref playersEP);
            ms.Write(data, 0, data.Length); 
            ms.Position = 0;
            Unit player = null; 
            player = bf.Deserialize(ms) as Unit;

            Console.Out.WriteLine(player.name + " " + player.position.X + " " + player.position.Y);
            ms.Dispose(); //and here
            for (int i = 0; i < players.Length; i++)
            {
                if (players[i] != null && player.ID == players[i].ID)
                {
                    players[i] = player;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Good day user1181369,

I've not used MemoryStream before myself, but I've been doing a little research through the MSDN library and my suspicion is that 'ms' is not clearing and all data you've loaded is actually being added to the stream, rather than replacing it.

MemorySteam.Flush(), for example, doesn't actually do anything (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.flush.aspx). If this is the case, then the for-loop would break upon finding the first instance of a specific player ID, not finding the newer versions.

Also, I am uncertain how the code you have supplied would deserialise multiple players, but that is outside the scope of this question and also, perhaps, beyond my current field of knowledge.

Regrettably, while I think I may have diagnosed the problem, I am not equipped at this point to offer a solution beyond instantiating a new memorystream in each loop.